# Different layout on second page

Tags: pagination, archives, hierarchical

My homepage has 1 featured post, followed by 4 posts stacked 2 on 2, like this:

[image]

The featured post is only shown on the first page so the second page shows the older posts stacked 2 by 2 as above.

However, I'd like to be able to change the layout on the second page, showing the posts in full width and length. Any way to do this?

tl;dr = How can I make the second page look different from the first page?

Comment: are you aware of the conditional tag `is_paged()` ? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load override WordPress' choice of template you can use `template_include` **filter** and then use the [`locate_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) to return the the template file path (if it finds it).

The file-name passed to `locate_template` must be the name of the template file name (which should be in you theme/child-theme directory).

```
//Loads template customtemplate.php from your theme folder on page 2+ of the 'main page'
function my_second_main_template($template){
    if (is_home() && is_paged()){
         $alternate_template = locate_template( 'customtemplate.php');
         if(!empty($alternate_template))
              $template =$alternate_template;
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include','my_second_main_template');
```

Comment: Seems to do the trick. I've made a new template and going to the second does use that new layout but it also repeat the body from the front page after the custom template....

Comment: @Jannemans I've updated my code, see if that fixes it :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I would make a separate template for home.php and a separate template for archive.php to achieve this.

Comment: This won't work - page 2 of the main page will still use the same template as the main page.